Create Deterministic address without create2
I wanna create a deterministic address in solidity without create2 bacause I'm not gonna deploy new contract. How do I do that?

Give us more details on what you're trying to do. What do you mean by creating a deterministic address without deploying a new contract?

It is quite easy to create a random address, but it will be difficult to do anything without the private key or deploying a contract.

As you have not provided enough details.
Assuming that you want to get the address of a contract before deploying it via CREATE.
Using ethers:
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const fetechFutureContract = async (deployer) => {
  const deployerAddress = await deployer.getAddress();
  const adminAddressTransactionCount = await deployer.getNonce();

  const expectedContractAddress = ethers.getCreateAddress({
    from: deployerAddress,
    nonce: adminAddressTransactionCount,
  });

  return expectedContractAddress;
};


Where, deployer is the signer.
const [deployerSigner] = await ethers.getSigners(); 
